# Response validation Doesn't work properly in ktor

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

So I have an API response like this :

If it succeed

```
{"success":true,"message":"user found","data": {data} }
```

If failed

```
{"success":false,"message":"user not found" }
```

the response code for the two above is 200.

After reading Ktor's documentation, we can use Response validation (https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html#2xx).

When I get a response with status = false, the validation is working properly.

But when I get response with status = true, I get this error

```
io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input
```

But if I don't use validationResponse, and get response API status = true everything is fine.

My code now

```
HttpResponseValidator {
            validateResponse { response ->
                val error: ErrorResponse = response.body()

                if (!error.success) {
                    if (error.message.equals("bad_password", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        throw ResponseException.BadPassword
                    } else {
                        if (error.message.isEmpty()) {
                            throw ResponseException.BadRequest
                        } else {
                            throw ResponseException.UnknownError(
                                error = error.message
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

@Serializable
data class ErrorResponse(
    @SerialName("message")
    val message: String,
    @SerialName("success")
    val success: Boolean
)
```

is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `HttpResponseValidator` consumes an HTTP response body, that's why you're getting the `JsonConvertException` after the validation is done (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4225). You can validate a response body after making each request as a workaround.

Comment: Any updates on this? The linked issue ticket shows no progress. Will it be available after 2.3.0? In 2.3.0 this is still broken